# Can't install mintupdate 4.5.6-1 (Linux Mint 16)

Tags: linux-mint, apt, upgrade

I can't install mintupdate 4.5.6-1 under Linux Mint 16.

When mintupdate tries to upgrade version 4.5.6 to version 4.5.6-1 the following error pops up:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (21: Is a directory)
E: Could not open file descriptor -1
E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The lock file is created to prevent concurrent installations. You need to close all instances of apt (synaptic, aptitude, apt-get) to make the upgrade. If you don't have any instance of apt running, probably the file remains for an aborted installation and you need to erese it manually.

For erease the lock file you need root privileges.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

How exactly can I do that? Could you provide a command line for that?

Cheers, Michael

Answer (score -1):

This seemed to do the job:

```
sudo rmdir /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Everything's work fine now.

Comment: That the answer i gave. You should upvote it.